# How to get NSURL of removable Volumes on OS X and notification when it mounts?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I need to detect when an USB drive e.g. Office23, is mounted in OS X and also search for a file eg. jan.txt inside the drive and copy it to app bundle.

I am using following method to find if volume is mounted or not:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error = error;

NSArray *keys = @[NSURLVolumeNameKey, NSURLVolumeIsRemovableKey, NSURLVolumeIsEjectableKey];
NSArray *volumeURL = [fileManager mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:keys options:NSVolumeEnumerationProduceFileReferenceURLs];

for (NSURL *url in volumeURL) {
    NSLog(@"URL %@", url);
}
```

**Result**: file:///.file/id=6571367.2/

How can I get the NSURL of the file inside Volume?

**EDIT 1:**

```
 NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLVolumeNameKey, NSURLVolumeIsRemovableKey, nil];
    NSArray *urls = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:keys options:0];
    NSURL *officeDriveURL;
    for (NSURL *url in urls) {
        NSError *error;
        NSNumber *isRemovable;
        NSString *volumeName;
        [url getResourceValue:&isRemovable forKey:NSURLVolumeIsRemovableKey error:&error];
        if ([isRemovable boolValue]) {
            [url getResourceValue:&volumeName forKey:NSURLVolumeNameKey error:&error];
            if ([[url absoluteString] containsString:@"Office"]) {
                officeDriveURL = url;
            }

        }
    }
    NSURL *fullURL = [officeDriveURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"documents/My File2.txt"];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:[fullURL absoluteString]]) {
        NSLog(@"YES FILE Exist %@", fullURL);
    }
```

**Still, FileManager cannot find the url.**

The fullURL is: file:///Volumes/Office/documents/My%File2.txt

When I check this through Finder or NSFileManager, this does not not work, but the path is correct.

Comment: Why are you passing `NSVolumeEnumerationProduceFileReferenceURLs`? The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/#//apple_ref/swift/structdata/NSVolumeEnumerationOptions/c:@E@NSVolumeEnumerationOptions@NSVolumeEnumerationProduceFileReferenceURLs) says that it will produce file reference URLs rather than path-based URLs. Pass zero as argument for `options` and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Cristik, I altered the method, and getting the Volume path but when I add the extension to it, NSFileManager cannot find it.

Comment: @Cristik, the path is correct, still unable to locate by it.

Comment: I mean, result is False for fileExistAtPath

Comment: Look at `NSWorkspaceDidMountNotification` of `NSWorkspace`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `FileManager` did not find the file using `[NSURL absoluteString]` method, When I removed **file://** from  `file:///Volumes/Office/documents/My%File2.txt` and also modified the %20, that got introduced (My%20File2,txt), it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[fullURL path]` instead of `[fullURL absoluteString]`

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:[fullURL path]]) {
    NSLog(@"YES FILE Exist %@", fullURL);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).